# Renaming project / solution in Visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to rename the project/solution name for example from Project1.sln to Project2.sln

Is that just simply by going to View > Properties Window then rename the Name property or there is an additional step?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Anecdotal, but I've had mixed success renaming projects. There's always something that never resolves correctly. I now always create a new project with the new project name.

Comment: I think this is a valid question what with renaming VS project files and solutions having some weird dependencies that break. OP could have worded the question clearer as a newcomer, but I don't think he should've been downvoted this hard. This isn't really something that's "try it out and answer it for yourself". He could have done the step already, but is wary of other side-effects leading him to ask here.

Answer (score 9):

Renaming projects could be challenging in visual studio, as vanilla visual studio won't help you much. (Read = manual editing files)

If you also want to rename the file system folder, follow these steps:

1. Rename the project in Visual Studio
2. Close the solution or unload the project
3. Rename the project folder outside Visual Studio.
4. Change the project name in solution file (.sln) with an text editor
5. Change project name in other projects which referenced(used) to it
6. (optional) Change assembly name and information
7. (optional)  Change default/root namespace

Comment: Thanks a lot, renaming the project in the .sln file via a text editor was the step I missed. This resulted in the error MSB3202 which blocked the build.

Answer (score 2):

Or you use a tool that I wrote for myself, that also deals with renaming in git so the history is not lost, moving to different directories etc.

Install via `dotnet tool install -g ModernRonin.ProjectRenamer`, see https://github.com/ModernRonin/ProjectRenamer for documentation.

Comment: what if project is not a git repo?

Comment: currently no supported, @kartooskhan, sorry. however, I take pull requests ;P

Answer (score 1):

If like most of us your namespaces are based on project names then you will need to rename all your namespaces to match. You will also need to change the default namespace of the project in the properties.